# How to check for an attribute from the list of objects in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list called `stops`. And it has `stop` objects with attributes (fields) `stop_id`, `stop_name` and `stop_type`. I need to check if all `stop_id` have the correct prefix or not.

I came up with following, but I am sure there has to be better way of traversing and matching:

```
stop_ids = [stop.stop_id for stop in stops]
for stop_id in stop_ids:
    if prefix in stop_id:
        pass
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) with [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if not all(stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix) for stop in stops):
    # at least one `stop_id` does *not* start with the prefix
```

You can also express this with the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(not stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix) for stop in stops):
    # at least one `stop_id` does *not* start with the prefix
```

If you want the `if` suite to be executed when all `stop_id` values do have the prefix, then use `all()` without the `not`:

```
if all(stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix) for stop in stops):
    # *all* `stop_id` values start with the prefix
```

Both `any()` and `all()` *short-circuit*; they stop iterating over the generator expression as soon as the first evidence is found that determines the outcome; for `all()` as soon as one `False` is found iteration ends and `False` is returned, for `any()` iteration stops with the first `True`.

Note that I used `str.startswith()` rather than `in` to test if the id starts with the given prefix; the `in` membership test would allow the prefix to appear anywhere in the string, not just the start.

If you need to list values that don't match, use a list comprehension:

```
not_prefixed = [stop for stop in stops if not stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix)]
if not_prefixed:
    # you have `stop_id` values that are not properly prefixed
```

I collected `stop` objects here, but you can also collect the `stop_id` values if that is more convenient:

```
not_prefixed = [stop.stop_id for stop in stops if not stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix)]
```

but if you only need to get the first, then again generator expressions are the answer here, combined with the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
not_prefixed = next((stop.stop_id for stop in stops if not stop.stop_id.startswith(prefix)), None)
if not_prefixed is not None:
    # you have at least one stop_id that wasn't prefixed, the first 
    # such is stored in not_prefixed.
```

Comment: Actually, I need to point out which stop_id doesn't have the required prefix too..

Comment: hey, thanks. Actually, is there anyway to stop iteration as soon as first non prefixed is found??

Comment: @IshanBhatt: sure, use `next()`. Added that too.

Answer (score 0):

`stops` whose stop_id is invalid

```
invalid_stops = filter(lambda x: not x.stop_id.startswith(prefix), stops)
```